# Laravel Passport - Rest Api

Tags: php, laravel, api

I get such a record not found error when sending request from postman.

Following my code :

`users` Table

```
id | name  | email           |password |
---  ------ -------            --------   

1  | admin | admin@admin.com | 123
```

`auth.php`

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

`api.php`

```
Route::post('login',[ApiController::class,'login']);
```

`ApiController.php`

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentails = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];
        if (Auth::attempt($credentails))
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('Login')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success],200);

        }
        else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'No Records Found.'],401);
        }
    }
```

***The output is in the picture below***
[image]

Comment: Why are you storing password like that?

Comment: for testing purposes only

Comment: It won't work with laravel since it always compares based on Hash logic and not string to string comparison